# AutoResizing Image no imageView

Tags: iphone, uiimage, autoresizingmask

i am using AFOpenFlow in my app, but now the Problem is, 
the pictures I use are not the same size because they are from the web!
And how can i autoResizing the image at the view of the iPhone???
Here is my code from this method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // loading images into the queue

    loadImagesOperationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];


    NSString *imageName;
    for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
        imageName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"cover_%d.jpg", i];
        [(AFOpenFlowView *)self.view setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] forIndex:i];
        [imageName release];
        NSLog(@"%d is the index",i);

    }
    [(AFOpenFlowView *)self.view setNumberOfImages:10];


}
```

Thank you beforehand 
Marco

Comment: why don't you use a UIImageView to display the images?, you can choose how the image data is displayed within that view. You could then take the data out of that view and turn it to a jpg if you wanted.

Comment: Yes i have tried it, but i don't know how to implement and this code an UIImageView

Comment: The Problem is in the loop the second line (the long one), how can i implement there an UIImageView??

Answer (score 1):

scale your image before set to open flow
change your code in the loop as below:

```
imageName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"cover_%d.jpg", i];
UIImage *oriImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
[imageName release];

UIImage *requiredImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[oriImage CGImage] scale:768/520.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

[(AFOpenFlowView *)self.view setImage:requiredImage forIndex:i];
NSLog(@"%d is the index",i);
```